# How to send proactive message in MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

As a part of a use case, I  want to send user a proactive message from bot.
I am following this document related to sending proactive messages to bot.([Send Proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet))

I am trying to send proactive message to the user when the user has not interacted with bot previously.
For this scenario, I need to call 'Install App for Users' graph API and cache the necessary values from the conversation Update event bot receives upon installation.([Send proactive message when user has not interacted with bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http))

However, the permissions required to call this API are marked in private preview mode on the permissions reference page.
([Permission Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference))
I want to know if there is any other way to send proactive message to bot other than the way mentioned above.
I am attaching the screenshot of documentation for reference.

[image: Permission in Private Preview]
[image: Permission in private preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed this issue in Mail.

To install an app in the personal scope for all users in the tenant, you can do one of the following:

1. ```
    App only permission: TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteForUser.All
   ```
2. ```
    Delegated permission: TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteForUser   -> but the token must belong to that of a Teams Service or Tenant Admin.
   ```

The ‘Self’ equivalent of these permissions allow the caller to install only those Teams app that have declared the app that is making the request as webApplicationInfo.Id in its manifest.

Comment: Also, TeamsAppInstallation peemissions are not in private preview mode, document needs to be updated.

Comment: @sridevi-msft  Can you please elaborate what *Teams Service* means in this context?  "but the token must belong to that of a Teams Service or Tenant Admin."

Answer (score 0):

From the [Teams App Install permissions reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-platform-service-description/office-365-plan-options), installing an application for the user can also use this permission: `TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteForUser`. Although this is more privileged permission and requires admin consent, this is what should be used given that `TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForUser` is in private preview.

Comment: Hi @Chaitnya Joshi, Please let us know does that help clarify.

Comment: @Sridevi-MSFT  Permission 'TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteForUser' is also marked in private preview. You can refere [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference) documentation.

Comment: @ChaitnyaJoshi I'm not seeing where that permission is marked private preview from the link shared, would you clarify?

Comment: @Diana On the same page the permissions is marked in private preview. Please refre to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#teams-app-installation-permissions-private-preview) exact link. Somewhere it is marked in private preview and somewhere it is not marked in private preview. I have also checked other permissions available for this API. Those permissions are also marked in private preview in this documentation.

Comment: @Diana  I have attached screenshots in the question, please take a look.